# my hosting error 500 if use .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

my hosting error 500 if use .htaccess
this my .htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    AllowOverride All
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^developer.html$            developer.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^multishrink.html$          multishrink.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^stats.html$                public-stats.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^feed.rss                   feed.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.qrcode$           qrcode.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^api.php$                   API/simple.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^API/write/(get|post)$      API/write.php?method=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^API/read/(get|post)$       API/read.php?method=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/stats$             stats.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/unlock$            unlock.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^privacy.html$              privacy.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^disclaimer.html$           disclaimer.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^contact.html$              contact.php [QSA,L]



    # If path is not a directory or file then apply RewriteRule

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d        
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,60})$      go.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]Options -Indexes
```

how to fix this

Comment: Remove this line `AllowOverride All` .

Comment: remains the same as 500 error

Comment: I think the problem is on this line 
`RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,60})$      go.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]Options -Indexes`
if i delete this line, 
`Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.`